# Runtime Userform - Accessing data input

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a userform (variable amount of input boxes) at runtime with the following code:

```
Private sub Userform_Initialize()

Dim num as Long
Dim i as long

Dim inputBx as Control

num = 10
For i=1 to num

'Referencing the name of textboxes for later

Set inputBx = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1","inputBx" & i)
With inputBx
.Height = 20
.Width = 100
.Left = 20
.Top = 20 * i
End With

Next i
```

And this works perfectly, it creates the boxes just as I want them. I also created a button in the useform manually to submit the inputs in these boxes but I can't seem to get it to work to write data where i want. This is what I tried

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_click()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Workseets("Test")

For i = 1 to num
ws.Range("A" & i).Value = "inputBx"&i.Value

Next i
End Sub
```

I have also tried just using these to see if I could see what data was there

```
MsgBox(Me.inputBx1) 
MsgBox(Me.inputBx1.Value)
MsgBox(inputBx1.Value)
```

but nothing I do seems to work so how can I point to the data in the text boxes so that I can paste the input data somewhere in a sheet?

Comment: `For i = 1 To num: ws.Range("A" & i).Value = Me.Controls("inputBx" & i).Value:   Next i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
ws.Range("A" & i).Value = Me.Controls("inputBx" & CStr(i)).Value
```